# How to stop Reporting Services Blocking requests?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We are using `Reporting Services 2005` on `SQL 2005` and when a report is running then Reporting Services seems to block for that user. e.g. navigating in `/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` will wait until the report finishes before displaying anything. I have had a look at the `rsreportserver.config` file but nothing in there seems to be limiting things. Also it doesn't seem to be `IIS` that is blocking.

If the answer to this is Upgrade to `2008` then that is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It blocks per browser instance. If you start a seperate IE process then you should be able to run multiple reports

Comment: Thanks I have verified that, but it's a bit awkward to get users to do that!

Comment: My past investigations indicated that it has to do with the way SSRS deals with session locks (you can check the tempdb session lock table to monitor the locks in realtime). I'd be interested to see if others have work arounds to this.